# My nested dropdown menus are not coming on bringing mouse over in navigation bar while designing a website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, nav

I have started designing a website using HTML CSS Bootstrap and while making navigation menu dropdown menu is not coming on bringing mouse over instead its showing under it
I am hereby attaching the required code

```
                <ul class="main-menu sf-menu">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="know-your-branches-ao.php">Know Your AO/Region/Branch</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="hr-section.php">HR Section</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">General Banking</a>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"> RajBhasha </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Security </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Miscellaneous </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    </li>
                     <li><a href="#"> Advances  </a></li>

                    <li><a href="it-section.php">IT Section</a>

                    </li>
                     <li><a href="#">Regions</a>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="region-nainital.php">Region 1:Nainital </a></li>
                        <li><a href="region-almora.php">Region 2: Almora </a></li>
                        <li><a href="region-pithoragarh-and-champawat.php">Region 3: Pithoragarh and Champawat </a></li>
                        <li><a href="region-bageshwar-and-chamoli.php">Region 4: Bageshwar and Chamoli </a></li>
                        <li><a href="region-udhamsingnagar.php">Region 5: Udham Singh Nagar </a> </li>
                        </ul>

                     </li>
                    <li><a href="news.php">News </a>
                    </li>


                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Staff Corner</a></li>


                </ul> <!-- /.main-menu -->


        </nav>
```

The result is like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtqyD.png)

Please Help....

Answer (score 0):

First add class "dropdwon" in li which you want to make dropdown. Second add class "dropdown-menu" on ul

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav mainNavigation">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> About Us </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Marketing Services </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> IT Management Services </a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"> Molex Portfolio </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"> Fibre Products </a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Copper Products </a> </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Employment Opp </a></li>

          </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
```

and add this css

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu{ display:block; }
```

Comment: Thanks Ankit for your help

But I have used nested ul in an li inside <nav> and while hovering I was getting the required result

But not this time

Why????

Comment: no your code is perfectly fine and its running but i cannot understand why in my previous website it was working the way i have earlier created and not in this website 
if you want i can attach you the code